# Mudar o dados da tela alterar a partir do ID que está no Combobox

Tags: php, mysql

Estou travado no código onde não consigo retornar todas as posições do ID do banco no combobox e não consigo apartir desse ID alterar os outros campos.Qualquer ajuda agradeço desde já

Tela da Query dos Dados

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $ID_Cliente = $_SESSION['ID_Cliente'];


    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $consulta= "select * from pedido where ClienteID_Cliente='$ID_Cliente' " ;
    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível Consultar os seus dados.");


      while($consulta=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $Tipo_Servico=$consulta["Tipo_Servico"];
        $DataVisita=$consulta["DataVisita"];
        $HoraVisita=$consulta["HoraVisita"];
        $EnderecoVisita=$consulta["EnderecoVisita"];          


      }

        $listarID= "select ID_Pedido from pedido " ;
        $lista=mysql_query($listarID,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível Consultar os seus dados.");


          while($dados=mysql_fetch_array($lista)){

        $ID_Pedido=$dados["ID_Pedido"]; 

         }  

 ?>
```

Formulario de Alterar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto Web-AlterarPedido</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/layoutPrincipal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/formulario.css">

</head>
<body>

<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="../login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>



<section id="form">
    <fieldset id="form_field">
        <legend id="form_legend">Alterar Pedido</legend>

         <?php
        include "listarpedido.php";
              ?>

              <form method="post" action="alterarpedido.php">
                 Escolher qual alterar: <select name="ID_Pedido" id="ID" >
                 <option value="<?php echo $ID_Pedido;?>"><?php echo $ID_Pedido;?></option> 
                  </select><br/><br/>
                 Tipo de Serviço: <select name="Tipo_Servico"  value="<?php echo $Tipo_Servico;?>">
                 <option name="Reforma Predial">Reforma Predial</option>
                 <option name="Jardinagem">Jardinagem</option>
                 <option name="Eletricista">Eletricista</option>
                 <option name="Encanador">Encanador</option>
                 </select> 
                 Data de Visita: <input type="text" name="DataVisita" value="<?php echo $DataVisita;?>">  
                 Hora de Visita: <input type="text" name="HoraVisita" value="<?php echo $HoraVisita;?>"><br/><br/>
                 Endereço de Visita: <input type="text" name="EnderecoVisita" value="<?php echo $EnderecoVisita;?>" >
                <fieldset id="form_field">
                      <legend id="form_legend">Alterar</legend>
                      <input type="submit" id="botao" value="Alterar">
                      <input type="reset" id="botao" value="Resetar">
                </fieldset>
            </form>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Tela de Query de Alterar os Dados no Banco

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto Web-AlterarCadastro</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/layoutPrincipal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/formulario.css">

</head>
<body>

<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/Logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="../login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<section id="form">
    <?php

    $ID_Pedido=$_POST["ID_Pedido"];
    $Tipo_Servico=$_POST["$Tipo_Servico"];
    $DataVisita=$_POST["DataVisita"];
    $HoraVisita=$_POST["HoraVisita"];
    $EnderecoVisita=$_POST["EnderecoVisita"];




    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $atualiza= "update cliente set Tipo_Servico='$Tipo_Servico',DataVisita='$DataVisita',HoraVisita='$HoraVisita',EnderecoVisita='$EnderecoVisita' WHERE ID_Pedido='$ID_Pedido'" ;
    mysql_query($atualiza,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível executar a atualização.");
    mysql_close($conexao);



    echo"<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Dados do Pedido</legend>
  <p>Dados do Pedido Alterados com Sucesso !!!</p></fieldset>";



    ?>
<fieldset id="form_field">
     <legend id="form_legend">Voltar</legend>
    <a href="../menucliente.html" id="botao">Voltar</a>
</fieldset>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Não** use `Trecho de código` (Stack Snippets) para PHP, leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635

Comment: 1. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178868/recuperar-e-armazenar-o-id-apartir-de-uma-tela-de-login-para-usar-em-outras-tela
2. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180948/recuperar-um-id-e-inserir-no-combobox-para-alterardados
3. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181240/mudar-o-dados-da-tela-alterar-a-partir-do-id-que-est%c3%a1-no-combobox

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente: na sua "Tela da Query dos Dados", ao fazer a leitura dos valores retornados (dentro dos "while"), você somente atribui os resultados as variáveis.

Você precisa imprimí-los para o usuário, juntamente com alguma marcação, seja um link, um select (combo) e seus respectivos options, ou algo do gênero.

Comment: Ficou muito vago não entendi direito e como eu faria isso ?

Comment: o laco de repetição eu conseguir fazer mas  mudar os campos de acordo com o o ID,estou sem idéia de como fazer isso